# Use Enum in Primefaces JSF

Tags: jsf, enums

How use Enum in Primefaces?

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{mybean.cars}">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{EnumClass.VALUE1}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{EnumClass.VALUE2}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

CLASS ENUM

```
public enum EnumClass{
("Opel")VALUE1,
("BMW")VALUE2;
}
```

Using EnumClass.VALUE1 doesn't work, second thing is how pass parameter to dialog without using bean? It's possible? Maybe using composite attribute?